# How to track who is updating the bigquery records

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

When I update my bigquery table records from Airflow, I got this error

```
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Could not serialize access to table due to concurrent update
```

Where I can check who is updating the record at the same time?
Cause in log explorer, I only can see the insert job only, cannot found anything relate the update processs.